# How do I save a Destiny warp drive?

Tags: destiny

After acquiring a warp drive, how do you save it? I keep getting warp drives, but they keep disappearing.

Comment: You don't actually "keep" it. its a mission reward that is used to get a better ship.

Comment: Story-wise, that you got that warp drive will eventually make you able to travel to the moon, to venus, and to mars. You don't actually get to do that just because you got that warp-drive. The warp-drive was just an item you got in that mission as part of doing that mission. The warp-drive was then turned in to the shipwright to give you a better ship. Let's turn it around. If you're unable to complete the story where you get the warp drive you would be unable to go to mars, the moon, or venus, but not because you didn't get the drive, only because you didn't complete the mission.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are referring to the mission [Restoration](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Restoration) on earth then the warp drive you aquire is a quest item and not a "real" item. That means that it is of no use beyond a quest objective in the game.

In game world terms you need it the first time to allow travel off planet. Once you can do this you don't need another one.

In summary you can't save it because there is no point in saving it and nothing you could do with it if you somehow could save it.